# Good seeds to give as a gift to someone who is going to travel around the country

Tags: seeds

What seeds would you give as a gift to someone who is going to sell his/her belongings, and start a travel adventure around the country for a year?

The idea is that he/she could plant the seeds in different places, leaving something behind. I'm looking for any kinds of fruit/vegetable that would germinate in a variety of conditions (this will be in Australia).

I'm sorry if the question is naive or poorly phrased, I now next to nothing about gardening and flowers... this is just an idea I'm exploring.

Thank you!

Edit: I'm not asking about personal preferences or esthetics, but for facts about which seeds would have a better chance of germinating in a wide variety of conditions, as one would expect in the typical Australia weather.

Comment: ["Stack Exchange is about questions with objective, factual answers."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). This is very subjective, and one person's favorite plants may not be anything you'd like.

Comment: Apple seeds are the traditional answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Appleseed

Comment: @NiallC. I'm asking here because I'd like which type of seeds would grow in the variety of weather expected in Australia. I'd consider that factual, and based on experience.

Comment: @NiallC. I've edited the question clarifying what I put in my previous comment. Would you please consider reverting the hold? Thank you,